# How to partition a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to take a list (or a string) and split it into sub-lists of N elements. How do I do it in Haskell?

Example:

```
mysteryFunction 2 "abcdefgh"
["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
cabal update
cabal install split
```

And then use [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) from `Data.List.Split`

Comment: Note that if you have installed the Haskell Platform, you already have the `split` package installed. It's a very useful package you should have anyway!

Comment: Note that there is also `chunksOf` from `Data.Text` (package `text`) which works with a more efficient string implementation than lists of chars.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one option:

```
partition :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
partition _ [] = []
partition n xs = (take n xs) : (partition n (drop n xs))
```

And here's a tail recursive version of that function:

```
partition :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
partition n xs = partition' n xs []
  where
    partition' _ [] acc = reverse acc
    partition' n xs acc = partition' n (drop n xs) ((take n xs) : acc)
```

Comment: Because `(:)` is lazy, I would say that the first option is tail-recursive and the second is not.

Comment: @Toxaris Hmm, good point. Edit: But the first option will still require a non-constant amount of memory on the stack, while the second will not, right?

Comment: The problem with the **second option** is that as soon as the caller of partition requests the first `(:)` cell of the output list, `partition` has to traverse the whole input list to build an intermediate list, and then `reverse` has to traverse this whole intermediate list to find the first `(:)` cell of the overall output. I expect these traversals to require stack space. The **first option**, however, can immediately return the first `(:)` cell after checking that the input list is not empty. I see no need to use the stack there.

Comment: non-strict tail-recursion *bad*, guarded corecursion *good*. :)

Comment: Tail recursion on non-strict data structures *may* lead to accumulation of thunks instead of accumulation of intermediate data. It depends on the optimization level and how well ghc is able to perform strictness analysis.

Comment: Since both the second partition and reverse are implemented in a tail-recursive manner, neither will take more than a constant amount of stack space. Since the entire traversal needs to be done before you can get the first element, you won't accumulate thunks either. The only real advantage of the first one is that it doesn't have to build the result on the *heap* all at once, but can lazily calculate and dole out elements as they're asked for.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `splitAt` in the first version?

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
mysteryFunction :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mysteryFunction n list = unfoldr takeList list
  where takeList [] = Nothing
        takeList l  = Just $ splitAt n l
```

or alternatively:

```
mysteryFunction :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mysteryFunction n list = unfoldr (\l -> if null l then Nothing else Just $ splitAt n l) list
```

Note this puts any remaining elements in the last list, for example

```
mysteryFunction 2 "abcdefg" = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "g"]
```

Comment: This is instructive but I find the approach of @PaulManta to be easier to read (probably because (as a novice) I don't tend to use `unfoldr`.  Are there any performance considerations between the two approaches?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List 
import Data.Function

mysteryFunction n = map (map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . zip ([0..] >>= replicate n)
```

... just kidding...

Comment: Come on, you were not that far away from making it fully point-free and unreadable!

Comment: @Denomales Read it from right to left: First I build an infinite list with the right number of repetitions, e.g. `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2...]` and zip it together with our input list (point-free style, so I don't need an argument for this), which gives a list of pairs. Next I use `groupBy` in order to get the desired chunks based on my "number pattern", and as last step I remove the now no longer needed numbers with double-`map` (as I want to modify lists inside a list). However I would never use such a "train wreck" in real life.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysteryFunction x "" = []
mysteryFunction x s = take x s : mysteryFunction x (drop x s)
```

Probably not the elegant solution you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There's already

```
Prelude Data.List> :t either
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

and

```
Prelude Data.List> :t maybe
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

so there really should be

```
list :: t -> ([a] -> t) -> [a] -> t
list n _ [] = n
list _ c xs = c xs
```

as well. With it,

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)

g n = unfoldr $ list Nothing (Just . splitAt n)
```

without it,

```
g n = takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)
```

Answer (score 1):

A fancy answer.

In the answers above you have to use splitAt, which is recursive, too. Let's see how we can build a recursive solution from scratch.

Functor L(X)=1+A*X can map X into a 1 or split it into a pair of A and X, and has List(A) as its minimal fixed point: List(A) can be mapped into 1+A*List(A) and back using a isomorphism; in other words, we have one way to decompose a non-empty list, and only one way to represent a empty list.

Functor F(X)=List(A)+A*X is similar, but the tail of the list is no longer a empty list - "1" - so the functor is able to extract a value A or turn X into a list of As. Then List(A) is its fixed point (but no longer the minimal fixed point), the functor can represent any given list as a List, or as a pair of a element and a list. In effect, any coalgebra can "stop" decomposing the list "at will".

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data N a x = Z [a] | S a x deriving (Functor)
```

(which is the same as adding the following trivial instance):

```
instance Functor (N a) where
  fmap f (Z xs) = Z xs
  fmap f (S x y) = S x $ f y
```

Consider the definition of hylomorphism:

```
hylo :: (f b -> b) -> (c -> f c) -> c -> b
hylo psi phi = psi . fmap (hylo psi phi) . phi
```

Given a seed value, it uses phi to produce f c, to which fmap applies hylo psi phi recursively, and psi then extracts b from the fmapped structure f b.

A hylomorphism for the pair of (co)algebras for this functor is a splitAt:

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitAt n xs = hylo psi phi (n, xs) where
  phi (n, []) = Z []
  phi (0, xs) = Z xs
  phi (n, (x:xs)) = S x (n-1, xs)
```

This coalgebra extracts a head, as long as there is a head to extract and the counter of extracted elements is not zero. This is because of how the functor was defined: as long as phi produces S x y, hylo will feed y into phi as the next seed; once Z xs is produced, functor no longer applies hylo psi phi to it, and the recursion stops.

At the same time hylo will re-map the structure into a pair of lists:

```
  psi (Z ys) = ([], ys)
  psi (S h (t, b)) = (h:t, b)
```

So now we know how splitAt works. We can extend that to splitList using apomorphism:

```
splitList :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitList n xs = apo (hylo psi phi) (n, xs) where
  phi (n, []) = Z []
  phi (0, xs) = Z xs
  phi (n, (x:xs)) = S x (n-1, xs)

  psi (Z []) = Cons [] $ Left []
  psi (Z ys) = Cons [] $ Right (n, ys)
  psi (S h (Cons t b)) = Cons (h:t) b
```

This time the re-mapping is fitted for use with apomorphism: as long as it is Right, apomorphism will keep using hylo psi phi to produce the next element of the list; if it is Left, it produces the rest of the list in one step (in this case, just finishes off the list with []).