# Where to find chunks in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/String_IO.

In the last part *7 Extension: using SMP parallelism* I copy the code but it fails to compile with this error message

```
/home/dhilst/parallelspell.hs:13:20: error:
    Variable not in scope: chunk :: Int -> [String] -> t
```

I searched for *chunks* at Hoogle and got *Data.Text.Internal.Lazy*, but this seems to be an internal module. And I couldn't import it anyway.

Here is the code:

```
import Data.Set hiding (map)
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Char
import Text.Printf
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main = do
        (f,g,n) <- readFiles
        let dict = fromList (lines f)
            work = chunk n (words g)
        run n dict work

run n dict work = do
        chan <- newChan
        errs <- getChanContents chan
        mapM_ (forkIO . thread chan dict) (zip [1..n] work)
        wait n errs 0


wait n xs i = when (i < n) $ case xs of
        Nothing : ys -> wait n ys $! i+1
        Just s  : ys -> putStrLn s >> wait n ys i

thread chan dict (me,xs) = do
        mapM_ spellit xs
        writeChan chan Nothing
        where spellit w = when (spell dict w) $
                writeChan chan . Just $ printf "Thread %d: %-25s" (me::Int) w

spell d w = w `notMember` d

readFiles = do
        [s,n] <- getArgs
        f <- readFile "/usr/share/dict/words"
        g <- readFile s
        return (f,g, read n)
```

And here is the compilation line:

```
ghc -O --make -threaded parallelspell.hs
```

-- 
Update: I write my own version of *chunk* based on this quest:[How to partition a list in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427157/how-to-partition-a-list-in-haskell)

```
chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = []
chunk n xs = (take n xs) : (chunk n (drop n xs))
```

Still, does this means that the tutorial that I'm following is very old and out of date!? Can anyone confirm if that function already existed some day or if I'm missing something?

Regards,

Comment: Probably in [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunk).

Comment: Is this part of the haskell-platform or I had to install it? I tried to import but failed too. I suppose I have to use _cabal_ for installing this right?

I end up writhing my own version of chunk, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427157/how-to-partition-a-list-in-haskell

Comment: Pick your poison. https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.4/hoogle?q=chunk

Comment: _I searched for chunks at Hoogle and got Data.Text.Internal.Lazy, but this seems to be an internal module. And I couldn't import it anyway._

Comment: @geckos: You searched for "chunks", but the missing value is named "chunk".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the tutorial just forgot to define `chunk`. I encourage you to update the wiki to include a suitable definition.

Comment: Fixed at the wiki! Thanks for the suggestion, regards!!